# How do i make array with two specific interval?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
indicesC = np.arange(0, n**2-1+1, n+1)
indicesC2 = np.arange(n-1, n*(n-1)+1, n-1)
indicesC3 = np.concatenate((indicesC, indicesC2))
indicesC4 = np.delete(indicesC3, np.where(indicesC3 == 12))
print(np.sort(indicesC4))
```

`[ 0  4  6  8 16 18 20 24]`

When you run the code above, it's well-formed.

But, it seems too long code.

I want to write `indicesC`, `indicesC2` and `indicesC3` in 1 line.

In MATLAB, it is easy to perform like `indicesC = [0:n+1:n^2-1, n-1:n-1:n*(n-1)]`

It's a side note,

compared to MATLAB, Python is quite complex and seems to take a long time to adapt to the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this in 1 line :

```
n = 5
indicesC3 = np.concatenate((np.arange(0, n**2-1+1, n+1), np.arange(n-1, n*(n-1)+1, n-1)))
indicesC4 = np.delete(indicesC3, np.where(indicesC3 == 12))
print(np.sort(indicesC4))
```

Just replace the variable names used in C3 with the value you are suing to populate the variables.

You can also replace `indicesC3` from `indicesC4=np.delete(indicesC3, np.where(indicesC3 == 12))` by replacing `indicesC3` with `the value that I have assigned to it in the previous line`.

```
n = 5
indicesC4 = np.delete(np.concatenate((np.arange(0, n**2-1+1, n+1), np.arange(n-1, n*(n-1)+1, n-1))), np.where(indicesC3 == 12))
print(np.sort(indicesC4))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I solved problem thanks to you. I'm confuse about using [], () yet.

Comment: `[]` denotes a list in python where as `()` is used to call a `function/method`.

Comment: I can recommend few tutorials if you want to learn basics. Also, please upvote the answer if it solves your problem.